# Python / Remove special character from string

Tags: python

I'm writing server side in python.

I noticed that the client sent me one of the parameter like this:

```
"↵                        tryit1.tar↵                        "
```

I want to get rid of spaces (and for that I use the `replace` command), but I also want to get rid of the special character: "↵".

How can I get rid of this character (and other weird characters, which are not `-`,`_`,`*`,`.`) using python command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A regex would be good here:

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_*.]', '', my_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import string
>>> my_string = "↵                        tryit1.tar↵                        "
>>> acceptable_characters = string.letters + string.digits + "-_*."
>>> filter(lambda c: c in acceptable_characters, my_string)
'tryit1.tar'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regex like this:

```
import re
string = "↵                        tryit1.tar↵                        "
print re.sub(r'[^\w.]', '', string)     #  tryit1.tar
```

Comment: this wont remove some special characters like TM and makes it `â`